# A better way to find a public IP in Python?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

So, I'm fairly new to Python.  That being said, I've been taking Dr. Chucks lovely courses on Coursera.  This of course, has led me to trying my hand at writing a program to fix a problem that I've been having.

I wanted to create a program that would take my public IP address, check it against what I have stored, and send me an update when it changed (Non-Static public IP).

So far, I've come up with this to handle the IP checking (with no small amount of help from this site and others...).  It includes Beautiful Soup to help parse the HTML and Regular Expressions to help find the IP address from what's left from that.

This code works, but tear it up!  What would work better, or be more "pythonic"?  Yes, I wanted to incorporate some of Dr. Chuck's lessons in this, so maybe Beautiful Soup isn't needed.  Maybe there is a way to do this with less code?  I'm a NOOB, so be gentle...

```
import urllib
import ssl
from BeautifulSoup import *
import re

try:
    url = "https://www.ipchicken.com"

    scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url, context=scontext)
    data = uh.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    tags = soup('p')

x = tags[1].text

ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', x)
except:
    print "No network access detected, check connection"
    exit()
print ip[0]
myip = ip[0]
try:
    fhand = open('myip.txt')
    oldip = fhand.read()
except:
    fhand = open('myip.txt', 'w')
    fhand.write(myip)
    fhand.close()
    print "New IP file created."
    exit()
if oldip == myip:
    print "Current IP still matches"
    exit()
if oldip != myip:
    print "IP has CHANGED"
    fhand = open('myip.txt', 'w')
    fhand.write(myip)
    fhand.close()
    exit()
```

This was written on a Windows 10 machine, so it might not be able to create a new file in Linux (Raspbian), which is where I am eventually going to be transferring this to.  I'll have to give it a try and see if it works.  I would love to put this in the Chron directory and have it run every 15 minutes or something.

UPDATE:
I've found the bit to notify me of the change.  The new code is:

```
    import urllib
    import ssl
    from BeautifulSoup import *
    import re
    import smtplib
    try:
        url = "https://www.ipchicken.com"

        scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        uh = urllib.urlopen(url, context=scontext)
        data = uh.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        tags = soup('p')

        x = tags[1].text

        ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', x)
    except:
        print "No network access detected, check connection"
        exit()
    print ip[0]
    myip = ip[0]
    try:
        fhand = open('myip.txt')
        oldip = fhand.read()
    except:
        fhand = open('myip.txt', 'w')
        fhand.write(myip)
        fhand.close()
        print "New IP file created."
        exit()
    if oldip == myip:
        print "Current IP still matches"
        exit()
    if oldip != myip:
        print "IP has CHANGED"
        fhand = open('myip.txt', 'w')
        fhand.write(myip)
        fhand.close()

        user = 'youremail@gmail.com'
        password = 'yourpassword'

        recipients = ['yourcellnumber@vtext.com']
        sender = 'youremail@gmail.com'
        message = myip

        session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
        session.login(user, password)
        session.sendmail(sender, recipients, message)
        session.close()
        exit()
```

Now the code will send an email through gmail to my cell phone as a text (Verizon in my case).  Gmail is also nice enough to show this as a sent message when you look at the web portal as well.  It seems to take about 5-10 minutes to send the text, but it does work.  I've also noticed that if this code tries to send email less than 5 minutes apart, gmail errors it out.  That shouldn't be a problem, since IPs don't change that often.  Yes, you have to authorize less secure apps through the web browser (gmail.com) for this to work.

Comment: I have no comment yet on the bulk of your code, but there should be no need to query a remote website to get your IP (unless you're behind a router and you want it's IP). To get your local system's IP address, you can use `import socket; my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the icanhazip.com service. It provides you with just your public IP, without the need for you to filter it out with bs4.

So the overall code would just be:

```
import requests

def getPublicIP():
    r = requests.get("http://icanhazip.com")
    return r.content().strip()
```

The requests module is not in the standard library, see the following
link: [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: If you get "TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable" try r.text instead of r.content()